# how to make Scala canBuildFrom to build collection type from Seq to Set

Tags: scala, scala-collections, generic-programming, generic-collections

I did experiment on CanBuildFrom trait on Scala, it looks fine when I try to convert Array type to Seq type automatically, I think the reason is that we have CanBuildFrom[Array, T, Seq[T]] in the scope. However, if I try to convert Array to Set, it is not working. Further, Converting Seq to Set is not working as well. I just wonder should I define implicit into same type CanBuildFrom companion object to implement conversion ?. If it is, why scala doesnt provide it by default, is reason Set is a function ?

Here is the code which for Array to Seq

```
def transform[U[_]](col: Array[String])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Array[String], String, U[String]]): U[String] = {
    val builder = cbf()

    for (ele <- col) builder += ele

    builder.result()
  }

CanBuildFromSpec.transform[Seq](Array("123", "3"))
```

If I want to convert to Array to Set or List, it is not working

```
CanBuildFromSpec.transform[List](Array("123", "3")) //compilation error, cannot construct
CanBuildFromSpec.transform[Set](Array("123", "3")) //compilation error, cannot construct
```

Comment: You can supply `collection.breakOut` as the `CanBuildFrom` to your `transform` to allow you to build any collection (any that can holds strings at least). Or you can declare an implicit `CanBuildFrom` of the needed type.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to reinvent a wheel - Scala collections have `to[C[_]]` method which allows conversion as you want it:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).to[Vector]
res0: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> Array(1, 2, 3).to[Seq]
res1: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)

scala> Seq(1, 2, 3).to[Set]
res2: Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
```

BTW, `CanBuildFrom` was introduced not for easy convertibility. It was needed in order for operations like `map()` or `filter()` to preserve original collection types.

Also `Array` is converted to `Seq` automatically not because of `CanBuildFrom` (that would imply that array contents are copied into the new sequence, which can be pretty inefficient), but because there is an implicit conversion from arrays to their wrappers providing `Seq` interface.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I know "to" can do stuff, but CanBuildForm is very useful for generic programming on Collection. For instance, if I want to apply for calculation logic on the collection and I dont want to duplicate function for different collection, CanBuildForm is a good choice. Thus, in this case, "asInstanceof" or "to" are not what I am looking for.